# Find the number of follower using tweepy

Tags: twitter, python-2.7

I have a list for followers:

`lof = [31536003, 15066760, 75862029]`

I can get the follower count for each follower in the list:

`user = tweepy.api.get_user(31536003)
 print user.followers_count`

However, I am trying to write a list comprehension that can return a list in python. The list should be a list of the follower count of my

lof = [31536003, 15066760, 75862029] and will look something like [100,200,300]

which means user 31536003 has 100 followers, user 15066760 has 200 followers and so on.

How to accomplish this using list comprehension?

Comment: This is the closest I have gotten  loc = [tweepy.api.get_user(friend).followers_count for friend in lof]

Comment: Does that not provide what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it does, but I am new to Python so wanted to know if there is a better way. Sorry for the inconvenience....sot sure if I'm supposed to delete the question now?

Comment: Looks pretty good to me :) Not sure of the protocol, but I guess you could post your answer and then mark it as accepted (since it is correct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer....

`loc = [tweepy.api.get_user(friend).followers_count for friend in lof]`

Comment: You should probably accept this as the correct answer to support future searchers.

Comment: Done, sorry about the delay!